# ManyToMany relationship not working when executing query (Spring Data JPA)

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a UserEntity and a RoleEntity.
The UserEntity contains a field "roles" which is of type HashSet and annotated with the @ManyToMany annotation.
When calling my custom query "findByEmail" it successfully fetches the UserEntity, but the roles set keeps empty.

Here some parts of the code:

#### UserEntity.java

```
package xyz.michaeltprojects.collchecklist.security.persistence;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.Email;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class UserEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private UUID id;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(min = 3, max = 30)
    private String username;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(min = 6, max = 50)
    @Email
    private String email;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 120)
    private String password;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_roles", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Set<RoleEntity> roles = new HashSet<>();

}
```

#### RoleEntity.java

```
package xyz.michaeltprojects.collchecklist.security.persistence;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.UUID;

@Entity
@Table(name = "roles")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class RoleEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private UUID id;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(length = 20)
    private ERole name;

}
```

#### UserRepository.java

```
package xyz.michaeltprojects.collchecklist.security.persistence;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.UUID;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<UserEntity, UUID> {

    Optional<UserEntity> findByEmail(String email);
    Boolean existsByUsername(String username);
    Boolean existsByEmail(String email);

}
```

#### Debug Output when calling findByEmail method

[image: UserEntity response object from findByEmail method]

#### Database tables "user_roles" and "roles"

[image: user_roles table]

[image: roles table]

Comment: Hello, try to remove `new HashSet<>()` from roles field.

Comment: I've tried, didn't work sadly

Comment: Also, you may try to remove @JoinTable annotation at all, because JPA will generate Many to Many relationship itself with default column names, if you are not afraid of different column names, because sometimes people use JPA without auto-creating tables and want to use their custom config

Comment: Also tried, didn't work. Also I had to set cascade to MERGE and REFRESH otherwise I would get the error "detached entity passed to persist"...
Another thing I noticed is that all the UUIDs in the database are followed by lots of zeros. I don't know why tho

Comment: JPA does not understand what you are referencing it with. Try my answer below.

Comment: Try to specify uuid generation strategy for both role en user entities. default strategy is auto. Try this If you are using at least Hibernate 6.2: 
@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
    private UUID id;

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `List roles = new ArrayList<>()`

In my code, I have used Set with ManyToMany relationship and I didn't get any associated vale after I changed the Set to List. I didn't understand Why the Set with hashSet didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. In my case, I was using hibernate and liquibase to update the schema. After updating the schema with liquibase and inserting some data using liquibase, I could not get any associated value with manytomany relationship.

After changing Set to List. I was able to get values
Like this

```
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@OrderBy(value = "createdOn")
private Set<UserAppServices> userAppServices;
```

To

```
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@OrderBy(value = "createdOn")
private List<UserAppServices> userAppServices;
```

Comment: I'm really not sure why but this happened to be a solution for me too right now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I've somehow solved the issue...
It seems that populating the relationships didn't work with UUIDs as identifiers. When I replaced them with longs it worked perfectly. Seems weird but it is like it is

Comment: "Now we'll look at the UUIDGenerator, which was introduced in Hibernate 5." @ Baeldung. Maybe you use Hibernate <5?

Comment: I use UUID on all my entities and it works well. For me, it was the Set<> that needed to be List<>. I use the UUID like this on 3.2.0 which means hibernate 6.3.1.Final:
```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
@UuidGenerator
@Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
private UUID id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You `ManyToMany` is not correct, you need to reference the id of each table by using `referencedColumnName`

Take a look at this one:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "user_roles",
     joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
     inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
private Set<RoleEntity> roles;
```

Comment: I tried it but it still didn't work. Also I had to change CascadeType to MERGE when adding the referencedColumnNames. Btw I've noticed something weird, in the user_roles table all the user_ids and role_ids start correctly with the corresponding UUID but end with tons of 0s...

Comment: use to make the ids auto increment and remove the ton of 0: `@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;` for your classes

Comment: @michael.tillmanns can you check the data in db, I think the problem is in your save function?

Comment: The data is saved successfully, also the Join table is there and all entries are fine. Just when querying the table and getting the UserEntity it gives me the correct UserEntity but with an empty "PersistenceSet" of RoleEntities

Comment: can you try with jpa findOne(UUID) function?

Comment: Also doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this? by adding an override function setRoles(..) below the UserEntity calss

```
package xyz.michaeltprojects.collchecklist.security.persistence;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.Email;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class UserEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private UUID id;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(min = 3, max = 30)
    private String username;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(min = 6, max = 50)
    @Email
    private String email;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 120)
    private String password;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_roles", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Set<RoleEntity> roles = new HashSet<>();

   public UserEntity setRoles(final Set<RoleEntity> roles) {
     this.roles.clear();
     if (roles != null) {
         this.roles.addAll(roles);
     }
     return this;
   }

}
```

Comment: It already set's the roles correctly and stores them to the database the issue is just that when querying it doesn't fetch the users roles to UserEntity object

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove `new HashSet<>();` from the user entity.

Comment: Already tried that, didn't work